# Twilio - handling calls blocked by geo permissions

Tags: twilio

I would like to handle calls blocked by geo permissions settings in Twilio.

My application is using Twilio to connect two people on the phone. We are achieving this by calling one participant with a callback set to return TwiML. The TwiML contains a Dial verb with the second participant's phone number. Sometimes the 2nd phone number is from a country that I don't want to allow calls, so geo permission settings are blocking those.

In this case, I am wasting the 1st participant time. I am looking for a way to check if the phone number is correct (allowed by the geo permission settings I have configured), or for a way to handle a blocked call gracefully (in event callback? is there a flag on a blocked call indicating what happened?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [action URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action) of the `<Dial>` verb to capture the failure using `DialCallStatus` and act accordingly.

You can set the [Debugger Webhook URL](https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger/alert-triggers), to a resource which will capture there [geographic permission errors](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/13227) (and other errors) and POST to your endpoint.

Comment: Using the action URL of the `Dial`, can I expect the `DialCallStatus` to be `failed`? 
Debugger Webhook won't work for me, unfortunately - I am using multiple Workspaces for multiple environments of my application, and debugger accepts only one callback endpoint.

Comment: Yes, it will be failed.